# gulp/node `del` package buckling under large glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, del

I have a rather complex build process (using gulp), which builds out (among many other things) about 95 javascript files into various folders scattered throughout a `build` directory. I would think simply executing `delete` of the `build` folder would be straightforward, but no matter what I try, I continuously get some variation of the following error:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/path/to/my/site/build/app/js/services/some-ever-changing-js-file.js'
    at Error (native)
```

Here is the extremely simple gulp task:

```
gulp.task('clean', '', cb => {
  del(['build'], { dryRun: false }, cb)
})
```

Additional Info:

- del: ^2.2.0
- gulp: ^3.9.0
- If I run the task twice, it only throws the first time.
- I have tried about every variation of file globs possible, such as `build/**`, `build/**/*.js`, `build/**/*.*`, always the same error, not always on the same file.
- Tried implementing `vinylPaths`-- got same result :sadpanda:

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Anyone know how to fix it or what could be the cause?

Comment: "The glob pattern matches all children and the parent." Are you creating `/build` in a later task so the first time through it doesn't yet exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out-- it had nothing to do with the build at all-- another application had this file open and it refused to delete it.